# how Remove certain character at Front and back of a varchar

Tags: sql, character

I have a customer data such as below

```
Table= Customer
field= CardNo
```

Data in `CardNo`:

```
%ABC?;9991?
%ABC?;99912?
%ABC?;999123?
%ABC?;888123?
```

Output i want is

```
9991
99912
999123
888123
```

However I want to remove all the "%ABC?;" at the front and "?" at the back, in the entire `CardNo` field. How I do it? I have tried this with no success:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET cardno = RIGHT(cardno, LEN(cardno) - 7)
```

I get an error:

```
"Return Error 
Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.
The statement has been terminated."
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sql Server has a substring function

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
UPDATE Table1 Set Cid=Replace(Left(Cid,Len(CID)-1),'%ABC?;','') FROM TABLE1
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8bf6/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mean exactly this, you should probably be more clear what your intended result is:

```
DECLARE @foo VARCHAR(32)
SET @foo = '%ABC?;888123?'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@foo, 7, LEN(@foo) - 7)
```

Result: 888123

As applied to your code:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET cardno = SUBSTRING(cardno, 7, LEN(cardno) - 7)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ccd36/1)

Answer (score 0):

[REPLACE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) will work well.  REPLACE('%ABC?;9991?', '%ABC?', '')

You can chain them together to remove the second ? as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather brute force way, considering all possibilities for the pattern:

```
UPDATE Customer
    SET cardno = (case when cardno like '[%]ABC[?];%[?]'
                       then substring(cardno, 6, len(cardno) - 7)
                       when cardno like '[%]ABC[?];%'
                       then substring(cardno, 6, len(cardno) - 6)
                       when cardno like '%[?]'
                       then substring(cardno, len(cardno) - 1)
                       else cardno
                  end)
```